# How i read a json google finance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets

I have this response from google finance:

```
response-of-url = // [ { "id": "666601" , ... }]
```

I use this method to read the json:

```
response = response.replace(/\/+/g,""); //to remove //
```

but when i read the json i don't obtain nothing:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

In var obj I get nothing.

How can I read the json data in javascript from google sheets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"// [ { "id": "666601" , ... }]" is not a valid string. if its not a valid string then you can not use JSON.parse(). If you want to really use it then response should come as string like '//[ { "id": "666601" , ... }]'.

```
var response = '//[ { "id": "666601" , ... }]'.replace(/\/+/g,"");
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Comment: With this method i don't obtain nothing in google sheets. What i make wrong?

Comment: Can you provide me the exact json what you are getting ? OR else provide me the API from where you want to make call...

Comment: this is the api: http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=[TICKER], example: http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=jnj

Comment: And this is the google script code:
function getJSONGoogleFinance2() {
  var url = encodeURI('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=jnj');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(response.getContentText().replace(/\/+/g,"")));
  return obj.id + '°' + obj.t;
}

Comment: I am not sure about the example URI you provided but I used "http://finance.google.com/finance/info" and it seems running  check --> http://jsfiddle.net/8zVxH/177/